# akka io tcp server

Tags: tcp, io, akka

I am using the new Akka IO and followed this [tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/io.html)(which is a simple server-client application). My server actor system code looks like this:

```
// create the sever system
    ActorSystem tcpServerSystem = ActorSystem.create("tcp-server-system");


    // create the tcp actor
    final ActorRef tcpServer = Tcp.get(tcpServerSystem).manager();

    // create the server actor;
    ActorRef serverActor = tcpServerSystem.actorOf(new Props(ServerActor.class).withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(5)), "server");

    // tell the tcp server to use an actor for listen connection on;
    final List<Inet.SocketOption> options = new ArrayList<Inet.SocketOption>();
    options.add(TcpSO.reuseAddress(true));

    tcpServer.tell(TcpMessage.bind(serverActor, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 12345), 10, options),
            serverActor);
```

The **ServerActor** class it's just a plain actor that on it's **onReceive** does the followings:

```
logger.info("Received: " + o);
    if (o instanceof Tcp.Connected){
        connectionActor = getSender();
        connectionActor.tell(TcpMessage.register(getSelf()), getSelf());
        ByteStringBuilder byteStringBuilder = new ByteStringBuilder();
        byteStringBuilder.putBytes("Hello Worlds".getBytes());
        connectionActor.tell(TcpMessage.write(byteStringBuilder.result()), getSelf());
    }
```

I am trying to test the server actor using netcat and have this "strange" behaviour: only the first client that connect tot the server is receiving the message send from the server. The nexts clients could connect to the server but does not receive the message. Also in debug mode the server actor doesn't get the **Tcp.Connected** message(except for the first connected client), so a registration message could not be sent to the client, althought the next clients could connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue in the 2.2-M1 milestone, where the problem was that the TcpListener didn't register AcceptInterest on the selector unless it reached the configured BatchAcceptLimit, leading to it not being notified of new accepts if there where only a few connections pending.

It has been fixed and will be part of the next milestone release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was suspected that the problems is linked with the NIO selector. I'am waiting for the next milestone.

Comment: It's already out: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/lRXIHNP1614

Comment: Thanks Viktor for the link. I've tested with the new milestone and it's ok. Now i reveiced all the needed events.